# jQuery change input text value

Tags: jquery

I can't find the right selector for:

```
<input maxlength="6" size="6" id="colorpickerField1" name="sitebg" value="#EEEEEE" type="text">
```

I want to change the value to = 000000. I need the selector to find the "name" not the id of the text input.

Shouldn't this work?:

```
$("text.sitebg").val("000000");
```

The presented solution does not work, what's the problem with this?

```
$.getJSON("http://www.mysitehere.org/wp-content/themes/ctr-theme/update_genform.php",function(data) {
    $("#form1").append(data.sitebg);
    $('input.sitebg').val('000000');
});
```

The JSON data is working correctly; the idea is to later pass the JSON values into the form input text values. But is not working :(

Answer (score 397, accepted):

no, you need to do something like:

```
$('input.sitebg').val('000000');
```

but you should really be using unique IDs if you can.

You can also get more specific, such as:

```
$('input[type=text].sitebg').val('000000');
```

EDIT:

do this to find your input based on the name attribute:

```
$('input[name=sitebg]').val('000000');
```

Comment: Why not use id, it's simple and understandable

Answer (score 52):

jQuery way to change value on text input field is:

```
$('#colorpickerField1').attr('value', '#000000')
```

this will change attribute `value` for the DOM element with ID  `#colorpickerField1` from `#EEEEEE` to `#000000`

Comment: hi, is this working for you on chrome console?

Comment: This's the perfect answer when you have any DOM element for change value or any property you want.

Answer (score 32):

Best practice is using the identify directly:

`$('#id').val('xxx');`

Comment: simple and best one :)

Comment: Why does this work but `document.getElementById("#id").value = 'xxx';` does not work for me? It does not change the text value that appears, only the DOM element's value property.

Comment: You already use ById method, # is for css notation. Remove it.

Answer (score 20):

When set the new value of element, you need call trigger change.

`$('element').val(newValue).trigger('change');`

Comment: This fixed a problem for me where the change event handler was getting called twice; once with the new value and then again with [attr=val]

Answer (score 3):

Just adding to Jason's answer, the `.` selector is only for classes.  If you want to select something other than the element, id, or class, you need to wrap it in square brackets.

e.g.

`$('element[attr=val]')`

Answer (score 0):

jQuery change input text value using parent class

```
$('.form-submit input.submit').val('Johnny Bravo');
```

- `.form-submit` is the parent class
- `Johnny Bravo` is the text that you want to change