# Change what is inside an input type text field

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have an input field as follows:

```
<input type="text" id="screen" maxlength="20">
```

When I type in it, I see text, but there is no change to the html reflecting this.

How do I change the text inside this input using jQuery?

I tried the following but it didn't work:

```
document.getElementById('screen').innerHTML = "10";
```

Comment: Use this => `document.getElementById('screen').value = "10";` OR with jQuery => `$('#screen').val("10");`

Comment: Thanks AlwaysHelping, that's what I was looking for

Comment: Happy to help. No worries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an older example of how to change an input value using JQuery:

[jQuery change input text value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5709258/11673302)

`$('#screen').val('10');`

Else with vanilla Javascript, AlwaysHelping is right with

`document.getElementById('screen').value = "10";`

Answer (score 0):

Use the `val` method:

```js
$('#screen').val(10);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="screen" maxlength="20">
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the "value" attribute of an *<input>* element.

```
document.getElementById("screen").value = 10;

// or if you select the element with chrome dev tool
$0.value = 10
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input#htmlattrdefvalue

Answer (score 0):

In order to do so, you can simply listen to the input cha

```js
function updateInput(inputValue){
console.log("User Input",inputValue)
}
```

```html
<input  type="text" name="myInput" oninput="updateInput(this.value)" />
```

nge and print it again on HTML.